# OpenShift container platform 4 how to open the activemq console

Tags: openshift, activemq-classic

I've created an activemq application (docker image rmohr/activemq)  in Openshift 4. The application is up and running. Now I would like to connect to the activemq console which is supposed to run on port 8161. When I click op the "Open URL" button next to the application icon, a URL opens in a browser.
I then add the port number 8161 at the end of the url, but a "502 Bad Gateway" is returned.
How can the activemq console be opened in a browser ?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an Openshift route to access AMQ console outside from cluster.
https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/routes.html

Comment: I added a sceenshot with the default route which was created automatically.  Isn't this a valid route ?

Comment: Please check whether the default route is set on 8161 port or not. If not please configure the route to 8161. To access the route from the browser no need for a port in the URL.

Comment: Do I need to edit the Services or Route YAML file ?  Can you provide the code on how to do this ?  many thanks

Comment: You have to edit your Route and make sure the target port is 8161

Comment: I removed the existing port difinition in the YAML file of Route,  and added the following :    port: 
    targetPort: 8161-tcp.         Now the activemq console starts.